# How to change size of tabs

Tags: android

Actually i have created a tab in my app.here there are three tabs..but thing is that i am not able to manage style in the tabsan morevere i want size of one tab larger than the others two i am sending my code u plese check it..

XML CODE:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_height="match_parent" 
android:layout_width="match_parent" 
android:orientation="horizontal"
>
```

```
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="5dp">
    <TabWidget
        android:id="@android:id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        />
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:padding="5dp" 
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

Java Code:

```
setContentView(R.layout.main);
    Resources res = getResources(); 
    TabHost tabHost = getTabHost();  
    TabHost.TabSpec spec; 
    Intent intent;  

    // Create an Intent to launch an Activity for the tab (to be reused)
    intent = new Intent().setClass(this, ContactActivity.class);

    spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("Contacts").setIndicator("Contacts",
                      res.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_tab_artists))
                  .setContent(intent);
    tabHost.addTab(spec);


    // Do the same for the other tabs
    intent = new Intent().setClass(this, CallActivity.class);
    spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("Call").setIndicator("Call",
                      res.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_tab_artists))
                  .setContent(intent);
    tabHost.addTab(spec);

    intent = new Intent().setClass(this, MyInfoActivity.class);
    spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("My Info").setIndicator("MyInfo",
                      res.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_tab_artists))
                  .setContent(intent);
    tabHost.addTab(spec);

   tabHost.setCurrentTab(2);
```

Comment: what is the method for `getTabHost()`? I am using Tabs inside the fragment so my host activity is `FragmentActivity`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Here the code for changing the size of tab

```
 Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
        int width = display.getWidth();
        
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);

       TabHost mTabHost = getTabHost();
      
       mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("tab_test1")
               .setIndicator((""),getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.mzl_05))
         .setContent(new Intent(this, NearBy.class)));
       mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("tab_test2")
               .setIndicator((""),getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.mzl_08))
         .setContent(new Intent(this, SearchBy.class)));
               mTabHost.setCurrentTab(0);
               mTabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(0).setLayoutParams(new
                 LinearLayout.LayoutParams((width/2)-2,50));
          mTabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(1).setLayoutParams(new
                     LinearLayout.LayoutParams((width/2)-2,50));
```

Comment: thank you
and yes this (Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();        int width = display.getWidth();        )
is very important, otherwise you'll have a hardcoded size

Comment: will it work for all devices?. height also we need to take programmatically.